# safely use translate.instant()

Tags: angular, typescript

I work with angular 7

I have two file  **arservice.json** and **enservice.json**

And I use this code in **app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgModule, Injector,LOCALE_ID, Injectable,APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import {AppSettings} from './app.settings';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {Ng2Webstorage, LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import {JhiEventManager} from 'ng-jhipster';
import {JhipsterCoreModule} from '../app/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/auth.interceptor';
import {AuthExpiredInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/auth-expired.interceptor';
import {ErrorHandlerInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/errorhandler.interceptor';
import {NotificationInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/notification.interceptor';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader,TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CookieModule} from 'ngx-cookie';
import {NotFoundComponent} from "app/pages/errors/not-found/not-found.component";
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {CalendarModule} from "angular-calendar";
import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';


import { LOCATION_INITIALIZED, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeAr from '@angular/common/locales/ar';
import localeArExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/ar';
registerLocaleData(localeAr, 'ar', localeArExtra);


export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', 'service.json?_=12546887');
}



@Injectable()
export class NoCacheHeadersInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                 Pragma: 'no-cache'
            }
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);    
    }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),

    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyBssaasaspYE0'
    }),
    routing,
    Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
    JhipsterCoreModule,   
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),

    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    CalendarModule.forRoot(),
    NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule
    
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'ar-AR' },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [Injector]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [JhiEventManager]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [Injector]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NoCacheHeadersInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
 
    AppSettings
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]


})
export class AppModule {
}
```

and in html component I use this kind of code :

{{ translate.instant('serviceApp.mainMenu.main')}}

but the problem when I use this function :`location.reload();` is in sometime

```
{{ translate.instant('serviceApp.mainMenu.main')}}
```

show the correct label which is in arabic language
and Sometime show the label in english format and Sometime show
this message: `serviceApp.mainMenu.main`

and I try to add this code in constructor of the component in order
to load translate and add default lnaguage :

```
 constructor(
    public translate: TranslateService,location: Location, 
    private boot: BootstrapConfigService,private injector: Injector
    , private CheckLanguageService:CheckLanguageService) {
    
      console.log(navigator.mediaDevices);
      this.boot.boot();

      const defaultLang = 'ar';
      translate.addLangs(['en', 'ar']);
      translate.setDefaultLang(defaultLang);
      this.CheckLanguageService.checkLanguage();
     

  }
```

and this is the related code :

**check-language-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class CheckLanguageService {

    public  defaultTranslate:string=null;

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private translate: TranslateService
        ,private cookieService: CookieService) {
     
    }


    public checkLanguage()
    {
        const htmlTag = this.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0] as HTMLHtmlElement;

        if(htmlTag.dir=='rtl')
        {
            this.defaultTranslate='ar';
        }
        else if(htmlTag.dir=='ltr')
        {
            this.defaultTranslate='en';
        }
        else
        {
          this.defaultTranslate='ar';
        }

        this.cookieService.put('be_lang', this.defaultTranslate);
        this.translate.use(this.defaultTranslate);

    }

}
```

and **bootstrap-config.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { Observable, of ,  Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { JhiLanguageService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import {Location} from "@angular/common";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BootstrapConfigService {

  public langs: string[] = [];
  public currentLang: string=null;
  private currentLangChangedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private currentLangChangedSource$ = this.currentLangChangedSource.asObservable();
  renderer: Renderer2 = null;

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private languageService: JhiLanguageService,
    private rootRenderer: RendererFactory2, private router: Router,  private location: Location ) {
  
    this.renderer = rootRenderer.createRenderer(document.querySelector('html'), null);
  }

  public boot(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.currentLang = this.checkEmptyValue(this.cookieService.get('be_lang')) ? 'ar' : this.cookieService.get('be_lang');


   this.cookieService.put('be_lang', this.currentLang);

    this.translate.use(this.currentLang);
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(this.currentLang);
    
    this.renderer.setAttribute(
      document.querySelector('html'),
      'dir',
      this.currentLang === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
    );

    
    return of(true);
  }

  public doAfterCurrentLangChanged(next: (value: string) => void) {
    return this.currentLangChangedSource$.subscribe(next);
  }

  public setCurrentLang(lang: string) {
    this.cookieService.put('be_lang', lang);
    this.currentLang = lang;
    this.currentLangChangedSource.next(lang);
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(lang);
    this.updatePageDirection(lang);
  }

  public getCurrentLang() {
    return this.cookieService.get('be_lang');
  }

  public updatePageDirection(lang: string) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(
        document.querySelector('html'),
        'dir',
        lang === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
    );
 

    this.router.navigate([this.location.path()]);
    location.reload();
  }


  checkEmptyValue(stringValue:any): boolean {
    if (typeof stringValue != 'undefined' && stringValue) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core):

> `instant(key: string|Array<string>, interpolateParams?: Object): string|Object`: Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the `get` method instead.

So you should not use instant if you don't known if the translations are loaded or not. The correct is to use `get` with an `| async` pipe, or your code should wait for translation load before calling the `instant` method

Answer (score 0):

Just use `translate` pipe.

```
{{ 'serviceApp.mainMenu.main' | translate }}
```